# .find() do Mongoose não retorna nada, quando deveria

Tags: query, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta ao MongoDb com Mongoose.

O parâmetro é um $in com um array cujo único valor é uma expressão regular que seleciona o objeto se o atributo "url" tem a string contida em "valor" com ou sem caracteres ao redor. Ou seja, a expressão regular dá match se a string buscada está contida na URL.

Porém, após o retorno do promisse da query.exec() o que retorna é [], uma array vazio. A questão é que eu tenho certeza que há no banco um doucumento cujo atributo url tem o valor passado contido, a busca deveria retornar esse atributo...

```
      async function buscarNoBdPorValorContido(model, atributo, valor){
     
        var valores = valor.split(` `)

        valores.forEach(async valor => {

            const query = model.find({url: {'$in': [`/.*${valor}.*`]}})
            console.log(query)
            const documentos = await query.exec()
            console.log(documentos)  //IMPRIME UM ARRAY VAZIO

        })
    }
```

Não consigo enxergar o que pode estar errado...
SObre o operador $in do Mongo, eu achei aqui: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-with-a-regular-expression

Ao dar console.log() no objeto query, o resultado é esse:

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
  _executionCount: 0,
  mongooseCollection: NativeCollection {
    collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    _closed: false,
    opts: {
      bufferCommands: true,
      capped: false,
      autoCreate: undefined,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      '$wasForceClosed': undefined
    },
    name: 'noticias',
    collectionName: 'noticias',
    conn: NativeConnection {
      base: [Mongoose],
      collections: [Object],
      models: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      replica: false,
      options: null,
      otherDbs: [],
      relatedDbs: {},
      states: [Object: null prototype],
      _readyState: 1,
      _closeCalled: false,
      _hasOpened: true,
      plugins: [],
      id: 0,
      _listening: false,
      _connectionOptions: [Object],
      name: 'covid-database',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017,
      user: undefined,
      pass: undefined,
      client: [MongoClient],
      '$initialConnection': [Promise],
      db: [Db]
    },
    queue: [],
    buffer: false,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
  model: Model { Noticia },
  schema: Schema {
    obj: { url: [Function: String] },
    paths: { url: [SchemaString], _id: [ObjectId], __v: [SchemaNumber] },
    aliases: {},
    subpaths: {},
    virtuals: { id: [VirtualType] },
    singleNestedPaths: {},
    nested: {},
    inherits: {},
    callQueue: [],
    _indexes: [],
    methods: {},
    methodOptions: {},
    statics: {},
    tree: {
      url: [Function: String],
      _id: [Object],
      __v: [Function: Number],
      id: [VirtualType]
    },
    query: {},
    childSchemas: [],
    plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    '$id': 1,
    s: { hooks: [Kareem] },
    _userProvidedOptions: { typeKey: '$type' },
    options: {
      typeKey: '$type',
      typePojoToMixed: true,
      id: true,
      noVirtualId: false,
      _id: true,
      noId: false,
      validateBeforeSave: true,
      read: null,
      shardKey: null,
      autoIndex: null,
      minimize: true,
      discriminatorKey: '__t',
      versionKey: '__v',
      capped: false,
      bufferCommands: true,
      strict: true,
      pluralization: true
    },
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
    _requiredpaths: []
  },
  op: 'find',
  options: {},
  _conditions: { url: { '$in': [Array] } },
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection: NodeCollection {
    collection: NativeCollection {
      collection: [Collection],
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      _closed: false,
      opts: [Object],
      name: 'noticias',
      collectionName: 'noticias',
      conn: [NativeConnection],
      queue: [],
      buffer: false,
      emitter: [EventEmitter]
    },
    collectionName: 'noticias'
  },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos problemas que eu vejo, é que você quer fazer uma query utilizando uma expressão regular, mas está utilizando uma string como parâmetro.

Na seguinte linha de código:

```
const query = model.find({url: {'$in': [`/.*${valor}.*`]}})
```

`` `/.*${valor}.*` `` é apenas uma string, para declarar uma expressão regular, você não a delimita com aspas, você a delimita com barras: `/exemplo/`. Para gerar uma expressão regular dinamicamente a partir de uma string, você precisa utilizar o construtor `RegExp`.

Então no seu código deveria ser

```
const query = model.find({url: {'$in': [new RegExp(`/.*${valor}.*`)]}})
```

Essa expressão regular também poderia ser simplificada, essa barra no começo parece estar errada, e o `.*` também é redundante para essa expressão. Então você poderia escrever simplesmente

```
const query = model.find({url: {'$in': [new RegExp(valor)]}})
```

Finalmente, o operador `$in` também é redundante se você está procurando por apenas uma expressão (e não várias), poderia escrever

```
const query = model.find({url: new RegExp(valor)})
```

E se quiser ignorar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, pode adicionar a flag `i`:

```
const query = model.find({url: new RegExp(valor, 'i')})
```

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas, vou começar a testar elas, e já volto